# What are the possible objdump demangle styles?

Tags: options

The manpage for `objdump` states:

```
--demangle[=style]
    ...
    The optional demangling style argument can be used to choose an appropriate demangling style for your compiler.
```

Nowhere does it mention what possible styles are recognized by the program. Wherever I have found reference to the `--demangle` option in form posts, there is also no mention of the possible style options. How can anyone find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked on the sources and I found the solution, and also I found some *misleading* information on objdump:

You should use `objdump -H` to get the list of available styles. Just running `objdump` give you misleading information: *-H Display this information*, which it is not. `-H` gives you much more data.

In any case, on my system:

```
-C, --demangle[=STYLE]         Decode mangled/processed symbol names
                               STYLE can be "none", "auto", "gnu-v3",
                               "java", "gnat", "dlang", "rust"
```

Note: not what I expected. I was thinking more C++ variants (anybody still remember the few ABI changes some years ago?)